# SARIMA model and forecasting

Tags: r, time-series, self-study, forecasting, arima

[image]

I am working on this question but have several difficulties:
1) First I identified the model as a SARIMA(0,0,1) x (0,0,0)$_3$.

2) Second, I calculated the variance as such: $\text{Var}(Y_t) = \phi^2\text{Var}(Y_{t-3}) + (1+ \theta^2) \sigma^2$ and $\text{Var}(Y_{t-3}) = \text{Var}(Y_t)$ and so $\text{Var}(Y_t) = \frac{(1+ \theta^2)\sigma^2}{1-\phi^2}$.

or 2.45 when $\phi=0.7, \theta=-0.5, \sigma=1$.

3) Third I calculated the forecast as $Y_{t+1} = ΦY_{t-2} – θe_t = (0.7)(-0.5)-(-0.5)0.95=0.125, 
with forecast error variance = σ^2+Var(Y_{t+1}) = 1+ Φ^2Var(Y_{t-2}) + θ^2 σ^2 or 3.45 when Φ=0.7, θ=-0.5, σ=1.$
But is it true $Y_{t+4} = Y_{t+4-3} = Y_{t+1}$ similarly with forecast error variance $= σ^2+Var(Y_{t+4})$ ?

5) Also I calculated 95% prediction intervals are 0.125 ± 2√1 = -1.875 to 2.125 and 0.125± 2√(1+〖0.7〗^2+〖0.5〗^2= -2.513 to 2.763 but I am not sure if that's correct..

I would appreciate it if anyone could specifically point out the correction for my mistakes where applicable.

Comment: This question needs the self study tag.

Comment: Take a look at my edit (the code behind it) if you want to learn a little $\LaTeX$ formatting and make your life easier when typing formulas. I edited only part 2, you can finish the rest if you like.